# neo4j - query error: expected Float or Integer but was Node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have these labels:

- profile
- page
- post

Now I'm trying this query:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH
    (pag:page),
    (pag)-[:AUTHOR]-(pos:post),
    (pos)-[:LIKED]-(likers:prof)
RETURN
    pag.name,
    count(pos)  AS totalPagePosts,
    sum(likers) AS totalPageLikes
```

Then I get this error:

```
File ":9:9": Type mismatch: expected Float or Integer but was Node (line 9, column 9)
"sum(likers) AS totalPageLikes"
```

How can I do this query?

Comment: use `count(distinct pos), count(distinct likers)`

Comment: this worked! post this as answer so I can mark! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use use a query like this:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH
    (pag:page),
    (pag)-[:AUTHOR]-(pos:post),
    (pos)-[:LIKED]-(likers:prof)
RETURN
    pag.name,
    count(distinct pos) AS totalPagePosts,
    count(distinct likers) AS totalPageLikes
```

`Sum()` is an aggregation function that sums up numeric values, `count()` just counts occurences.

See the [Cypher Ref Card](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.1.5/refcard/).